# error trying to run php files in MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I have installed MAMP on my mac (OS X 10.9.5) and am unable to get php files to work correctly.

My php file looks like:

```
<?php
phpinfo();?>
```

This file is stored in the MAMP/htdocs folder.

When I load this in a browser (tried Chrome and Safari) with http://localhost:8888/test.php, I get the following errors:

From the php_error.log:

> [19-Oct-2015 05:06:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php on line 9

From the apache_error.log:

> [Sun Oct 18 22:49:25 2015] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store

It looks like the version of MAMP that I have installed is running Apache2.2.
I'm new to this, and have researched a number of resources to get help.  I'm wondering if I need to edit the apache config file somehow?  Not sure what to change.  Would appreciate some advice!

I should also add that when I load a test1.php file (http://localhost:8888/test1.php) that just has basic html in it, everything works fine.

Comment: Please add your `test.php`.

Comment: test.php is the simple 2-line code shown at the beginning of my question.

Comment: which is line number 9 in `test.php`. Error is in that line.

Comment: Your posted source code doesn't have a syntax error in, as far as I can see. And it doesn't have nine lines, so it can't be causing the error you posted. (And your apache_error.log message looks like a red herring, especially since it's from about six hours before the PHP error.)

Comment: Thank you @John Conde.  Turns out the text editor I was using must have put some invisible characters in my file.  Once I recreated the file in another editor, things worked just fine!